# How can i find a partial match from output_value and match it to value in a dt_datatable then use the partial match found to add row

Tags: datatable, match, uipath, uipath-activity

How to find a partial match from output_value and match it to value in a dt_datatable then use the partial match found to add row

output_value = "12345600"

dt_datatable = {"123456", "263456"}

Thank you in advance.

Comment: anyone willing to help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, from your example above you dont have a datatable, it looks more like a list however for this answer I will assume that you have the following string called `output_value` and a datatable called `dt_datatable` with a single column called `partial`.

```
output_value = "12345600"
```

```
dt_datatable 

partial
"123456"
"263456"
```

The below line of code sort of answers the above question, it will identify the first row as this meets the criteria inferred in your question, `output_value` starts with whats in the row meaning they have a partial match.

```
dt_datatable.AsEnumerable.Where(Function (r) output_value.StartsWith(r.Item("partial").ToString())).CopyToDataTable()
```

This could be tweaked to use other string functions depending on your requirements, for example the below checks if `output_value` contains the string in the row rather than starts with it.

```
dt_datatable.AsEnumerable.Where(Function (r) output_value.Contains(r.Item("partial").ToString())).CopyToDataTable()
```

One of the difficult bits of development and it seems to crop up more in RPA is matching, you need to define exactly what you want to match on then create your rules around that. eg for a match it has to start with it not end with it, or it just must contain it etc...

Comment: thanks @Conor. I ideally want to find a match that starts with my output_value. Do you mind sending me an example?

Comment: So if you're wanting the match to be where the row starts with your `output_value` use the line `dt_datatable.AsEnumerable.Where(Function (r) output_value.StartsWith(r.Item("partial").ToString())).CopyToDataTable()` this will bring you all of the rows that `output_value` starts with

Comment: Hi @Conor, can I send you a workflow regarding the above to take a look at please? I would appreciate it.